# Aggressive response to 1.d4?

Tags: gambits, 1.d4, queens-gambit, aggressive-play

As black, against 1.d4, which aggressive response do I have?
I looked at queen's gambit accepted, queen's gambit declined, king's Indian defence and the Slav defence. But all of this options appear to me as passive, at least passive in the opening phase. Seems to me that in all this variations white still gets a better control of the center and a more active and developed setup, whit black that has no immediate treats or tricks. I am feeling like against 1.d4 I am doomed to play a more positional and passive opening phase. Is this the case?

I am a beginner, 1500, so is quite possibile that I am missing some aggressive potential in the mentioned openings. This comes from a guy that quite enjoys playing stuff like the fried liver, Stafford gambit, Evans gambit and the Danish gambit, so I hope you can get what I am searching here.

Comment: Benko, Benoni, Grunfeld are very aggressive openings.

Comment: most aggressive is 1. d4 e5, but as most of super-aggressive openings its not really correct :)

Comment: The King's Indian is definitely an aggressive choice, but aggression comes in the middlegame. Most "aggressive" openings just lead to the exchange of a lot of pieces when played correctly

Comment: @Drako I don't think 1.d4 e5 is more aggressive than the King's Indian or the Benoni

Comment: @David - not that it would matter for me but still - how you measure aggressiveness? In my opinion that's how impatient with attack you are - neither KID nor Benoni attacks on move one. But you could have different criteria and I'm not interest in defining those here in chat :)

Comment: @Drako I'd define it more about the odds of leaving your with initiative, rather than about the odds of having a premature attack that your opponent can easily defend

Answer (score 4):

I have no experience of playing it, but the [Albin countergambit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albin_Countergambit) 1. d4 d5 2. c4 e5 might be an option. It's relatively rare but doesn't seem to score too badly compared to the QGD/Slav, with significantly fewer draws than either (see stats [here](https://www.365chess.com/opening.php?m=4&n=23&ms=d4.d5.c4&ns=7.8.23)).